# Event not firing for dynamically created Label

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic

I have a Windows form with labels and I created a common click event handler for all the labels.
The event is bound from code. Now I need to create some more labels in run-time and bind the same event handler to those dynamically created labels. I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
private void Ctrl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control control = (Control)sender;
    if (control is Label)
    {
        Label lbl = (Label)sender;
        txtCaption.Text = lbl.Text;
        cboFont.Text = lbl.Font.FontFamily.Name;
        txtSize.Text = lbl.Font.Size.ToString();
        chkBold.Checked = lbl.Font.Bold;
        txtX.Text = lbl.Location.X.ToString();
        txtY.Text = lbl.Location.Y.ToString();
        txtWidth.Text = lbl.Width.ToString();
        gbLogo.Visible = false;
        gbControl.Visible = true;
        gbDetail.Visible = false;
    }
}

private void btnAddDynamic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    int count = pl.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList().Count;
    label.Location = new Point(50, (25 * count) + 2);
    label.AutoSize = true;
    Graphics g = label.CreateGraphics();
    label.Width =Convert.ToInt32(g.MeasureString(label.Text, label.Font).Width);
    label.Name = "label_" + (count + 1);
    label.Text = "label " + (count + 1);
    label.TabIndex=0;
    label.Click += new EventHandler(this.Ctrl_Click);
    pl.Controls.Add(label);
}
```

Comment: have you tried label.Click += Ctrl_Click; ?

Comment: Yes.......I tried it .

Comment: And can you confirm by setting a breakpoint on the first line of code in Ctrl_Click that the event is not fired on clicking on the new label ?

Comment: I also tested it that way.the event is not called on click

Comment: I just copy/pasted your code and it works on my end. Is there other code that may interfere ?

Comment: Try changing the `EventArgs` in the signature of `Ctrl_Click` to `RoutedEventArgs` and initialize the event handler accordingly.

Comment: It works perfect in my testapp. Perhaps the panel or the parent of the panel has the enabled property=false ? Do the labels that where created in designtime stil work ?

Comment: You aren't disposing the Graphic object you created.  Use TextRenderer.MeasureText instead.